# Combining multiple transformations in Eigen into one transformation matrix

Tags: c++, transformation, eigen, quaternions, affinetransform

I have several transformations in Eigen, in the form of translations (`Eigen::Vector3f`) and rotations (`Eigen::Quaternionf`). I would like to combine all these transformations, in an order of my choosing, into a 4x4 transformation matrix `Eigen::Matrix4f`.

For example, I would like to apply the following transformations in the order A, B, C, D, E:

```
Eigen::Vector3f translation_A;
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_B;
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_C;
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_D;
Eigen::Vector3f translation_E;
```

What is the simplest way of achieving this? I have so far been applying them individually to my final data like so:

```
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_in, *cloud_out, translation_A, IDENTITY_QUATERNION);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_out, *cloud_out, ZERO_TRANSLATION, rotation_B);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_out, *cloud_out, ZERO_TRANSLATION, rotation_C);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_out, *cloud_out, ZERO_TRANSLATION, rotation_D);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_out, *cloud_out, translation_E, IDENTITY_QUATERNION);
```

...but there must be a simple (built-in?) way of combining these transformations using Eigen, into a final 4x4 transformation matrix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a good tutorial in the Eigen docs: [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html)

In your case, this should look like:

```
Eigen::Vector3f trans_vec_A;
//note that you have to create a Translation because multiplying a 
//Transform with a vector will _apply_ the transform to the vector
Eigen::Translation<float,3> translation_A(trans_vec_A);
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_B;
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_C;
Eigen::Quaternionf rotation_D;
Eigen::Vector3f trans_vec_E;
Eigen::Translation<float,3> translation_E(trans_vec_E);
Eigen::Transform<float,3,Affine> combined = 
      translation_A * rotation_B * rotation_C * rotation_D * translation_E;
```

---

Note that

```
combined = A*B*C*D*E
```

so `combined` applied to a vector `v` is

```
combined*v = A*B*C*D*E*v = A*(B*(C*(D*(E*v))))
```

that is, `E` is applied first, then `D`, and so on. In my mind, this is the *correct* order, but that may be a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't give the same result as applying each separately. On a whim I tried reversing the order of the multiplications in the `combined` product, and it gave the correct result... Is this the way that Eigen transformations work? Starting 'from the back'?

Comment: @BillCheatham Yeah, they work "mathematically". I'll update my answer to show you how.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The ordering of transformations can be a little tricky I think. Thanks.

Comment: Does it matter whether I use the `pre` or regular transform functions in Eigen 3? e.g., if I do `rotation_B.prerotate` or `rotation_B.rotate`, will it make a difference for `combined`?